# Apply calculation to data occuring before current row in Pandas Groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
#Create DF
d = { 
     'Date': ['1/01/2021','2/01/2021','3/01/2021','4/01/2021','5/01/2021','6/01/2021','7/01/2021','8/01/2021','9/01/2021','10/01/2021','11/01/2021','12/01/2021','13/01/2021',
'14/01/2021','15/01/2021','16/01/2021'],
    'Name': ['Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','Joe','John','John','John','John','John','John','John'],
    'Criteria':[30,35,2.5,3,6,15,20,1.5,4,25,50,75,2,4,9,2],
    }

              
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%d/%m/%Y')
df = df.sort_values('Date')
df

      Date     Name   Criteria
0   2021-01-01  Joe     30.0
1   2021-01-02  Joe     35.0
2   2021-01-03  Joe     2.5
3   2021-01-04  Joe     3.0
4   2021-01-05  Joe      6.0
5   2021-01-06  Joe     15.0
6   2021-01-07  Joe     20.0
7   2021-01-08  Joe     1.5
8   2021-01-09  Joe     4.0
9   2021-01-10  John    25.0
10  2021-01-11  John    50.0
11  2021-01-12  John    75.0
12  2021-01-13  John    2.0
13  2021-01-14  John    4.0
14  2021-01-15  John    9.0
15  2021-01-16  John    2.0
```

I am using this in a machine learning model and I want to create a ranking by groupby but only include anything from up to the previous day (i.e. so the model does not know future values).

I have previously been using:

```
df['Rank'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Criteria'].rank(pct=True, ascending=False)
```

However this includes all future rows for the particular group.

How can I adjust this function to only calculate anything from the day before onwards?

Expected output (not using percentile):

```
df['Rank'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Criteria'].rank(ascending=False)

       Date    Name   Criteria       Rank
0   2021-01-01  Joe     30.0      NA
1   2021-01-02  Joe     35.0      1
2   2021-01-03  Joe     2.5       1
3   2021-01-04  Joe     3.0       2
4   2021-01-05  Joe      6.0      3
5   2021-01-06  Joe     15.0      4
6   2021-01-07  Joe     20.0      5
7   2021-01-08  Joe     1.5       1
8   2021-01-09  Joe     4.0       4
9   2021-01-10  John    25.0      1
10  2021-01-11  John    50.0      2
11  2021-01-12  John    75.0      3
12  2021-01-13  John    2.0       1
13  2021-01-14  John    4.0       2
14  2021-01-15  John    9.0       3
15  2021-01-16  John    2.0       2
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Please edit your question and include the expected output.

Comment: Its still unclear how did you got the expected output, Could you please explain in little more details?

Comment: For an example, index row 6. Joe has a `Criteria` of 6. The ranking is `3` because its the third lowest from index rows 0:5 (which are all rows that are grouped by Joe, and occure before the Date). Does that help? Thanks! @ShubhamSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you could just execute the groupby on a subset of the dataframe instead of applying it over the whole dataframe.

Since you have a `Date`column which contains the observation date for each data point, you could basically create your subset based on this column.

Say you have a `bound` variable which contains the limit between past dates (used for training) and future dates (used for testing / validation), you can restrict the full dataset to a smaller one using :

```py
bound = # Some date which splits the dataset in two
df_subset = df.loc[df["Date"] < bound]
df['Rank'] = df_subset.groupby(['Name'])['Criteria'].rank(pct=True, ascending=False)
```

Comment: Thanks AlexTorx. WOuld it be possible to get an example of that using my data? Im not sure what you meanby the `limit` variable

Comment: Well what I can see is that you have a `Date` column which I suppose represents the date of the observation for each data point. Since you are trying to build a predictive model, say there is a day which represents the limit between past data points (used for training) and future data points (used for testing / validation). Then the `limit` variable would be the index of the occurrence of this specific date. Does that make sense for you ?

Comment: Tahnks @AlexTorx. In my example `Date` isnt the index but essentially I would be looking to limit the rank to all rows which have a `Date` before the current date. So in that case would the `limit` be `Date minus 1 day`?

Comment: Exactly ! I will update my answer to make it more accurate regarding your specific case.

Comment: Thanks, ill check it out now!